# How do you access specific elements from the nested lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I  am trying to access elements from the nested lists.
For example,

```
file = [[“Name”,”Age”,”Medal”,”Location”],[“Jack”,”31”,”Gold”,”China”],[“Jim”,”29”,”Silver”,”US”]]
```

This data contains at least 3000 lists. I only want to put the data into a new list with the column Name and “Location”

Output should be: `[[“Name”,”Location”],[“Jack”,”China”],[“Jim”,”US”]]`

This looks like a data frame. But I cannot use any module to separate the columns. How can I code it using python built-in function and methods. I tried for loops but failed,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by slicing your array. See below:

```
newArr = [r[0:2] for r in oldArr]
```

Comment: What if the data is not side by side. If i want only Name and location ? Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Good question! You could do something like [[r[0], r[3]] for r in oldArr] instead!

Answer (score 1):

This is a list comprehension problem:

```
newfile = [row[0:2] for row in file]
```

Answer (score 0):

If we have any sequential data type like **`lists, strings, tuples, bytes, bytearrays, and ranges`**, then Python supports slice notation and we can traverse every character in the given list using for loop.

if we have a 2-dimensional or nested list then

```
file = [["Name","Age","Medal","Location"],["Jack","31","Gold","China"],["Jim","29","Silver","US"]]


for r in file:
    print(r)

OUTPUT:-
    ['Name', 'Age', 'Medal', 'Location']
    ['Jack', '31', 'Gold', 'China']
    ['Jim', '29', 'Silver', 'US']

# ----------------------------------------------------------------
# if we want only specific elements 
# then we use the slicing method
# ----------------------------------------------------------------
for r in file:
    print(r[0:2])

OUTPUT:-
    ['Name', 'Age']
    ['Jack', '31']
    ['Jim', '29']

# ----------------------------------------------------------------
# if we want to output as a list
# then we can use single line for loop
# ----------------------------------------------------------------

newFile = [r for r in file]
print(newFile)

OUTPUT:
    [['Name', 'Age', 'Medal', 'Location'], ['Jack', '31', 'Gold', 'China'], ['Jim', '29', 'Silver', 'US']]







# ----------------------------------------------------------------
# Output should be: [[“Name”,”Age”],[“Jack”,”31”],[“Jim”,”29”]]
# ----------------------------------------------------------------
newFile = [r[0:2] for r in file]
print(newFile)

OUTPUT:
    [['Name', 'Age'], ['Jack', '31'], ['Jim', '29']]
```

Comment: How about if we want Name and Location only. How the slice will become?