# How to filter the elements from nested lists composed of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to access elements from the nested lists. For example,

```
file = [["Name","Age","Medal","Location"],["Jack","31","Gold","China"],["Jim","29","Silver","US"]]
```

This data contains at least 3000 lists. I only want to put the data into a new list with the column Name and "Location"

Output should be: `[["Name", "Location"], ["Jack", "China"], ["Jim", "US"]]`

This looks like a data frame. But I cannot use any module to separate the columns. How can I code it using python built-in function and methods. I tried for loops but failed.

Comment: Didn't you ask this (with the same syntax issues) once already? Edit: [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72049516/3001761).

Comment: Yes. Actually, the other one is about data being side by side. It’s easy to do with slicing. My actual data is not side by side. I am out of idea how to do it

Answer (score 0):

**Input data:**

```py
file = [["Name","Age","Medal","Location"],["Jack","31","Gold","China"],["Jim","29","Silver","US"]]
```

**List comprehension** (original and first answer):

```py
target_list = [[item[0],item[-1]] for item in file]
```

**Basic `for` loop** (updated answer to fit OP requirements):

```py
target_list = []
for item in file:
    target_list.append([item[0],item[-1]])
```

Output for both approaches:

```
[['Name', 'Location'], ['Jack', 'China'], ['Jim', 'US']]
```

Comment: i tried it. But the output is ==> [‘Jim’, ‘US’]. Am i doing it wrong?
file = [["Nmae","Age","Medal","Location"],["Jack",31,"Gold","China"],["Jim",29,"Silve","US"]]
for item in file: 
   l = [item[0],item[-1]]
print (l)

Comment: That's because you did it differently from my answer (and @JanaL). We used a list comprehension approach which will give you the desired output. If you want to use a for loop, use this updated answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this is by using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Given that you want every first and fourth item in every one of your sublists, you can do something like

```py
file = [
    ["Name", "Age", "Medal", "Location"],
    ["Jack", 31, "Gold", "China"],
    ["Jim", 29, "Silver", "US"]
]


new_list = [[sublist[0], sublist[3]] for sublist in file]
```

This list comprehension reads as: create a new list with its elements being lists populated by the first and the fourth element of every sublist in the `file` variable.